# jQuery animate on click works once locally, but works multiple times in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery

I have tied a simple animation to a div's click event. The div should animate left by 50 pixels on each click. This happens on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QgYMu/2/

CSS:

```
#wally {
     width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 100px;
     top: 100px;
     background-color: red;
  }
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wally").click(grow);
});

function grow() {
   console.log("clicked");
   $(this).animate({width: "+=50"}, 1000);
}
```

However, on my machine the animation happens only once, although I can see that each click is being registered via the 'console.log("clicked");' statement.

Can anyone shed some light on what's wrong? (Happens in FF and Chrome).

Comment: Works for me in Chrome (28.0.1500.72).  I just pasted all your code into a single test.html file and added a <script> link to jquery 1.10.1.

Comment: Your fiddle uses jQuery 1.10.1, is that the same version you use in your local file?

Comment: @j08691 The local file uses jquery-1.10.0.min.js. You've prompted me to try 1.10.1 and 1.10.2, both minified and production versions, and they all work properly. It's just the 1.10.0 minified that's the problem. Another google finds some people with problems animating relative values in 1.10.0, like me. Changing to 10.0.2 now. Sorry to have bothered you, and thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 1.10 had a bug with relative animations that cause your issue which was fixed in 1.10.1.

See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13939